# Maximize a function over several variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, vector

I want to maximize the function,
$$S_{v}=\sum_{a \in\{1,-1\}^{n}}\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} v_{i}\right\|$$
over $v_{i}$ and a given $n$ (say $n$=3).

$v_i$ are unit vectors.

$a$ are lists with $n$ elements consisting of $1$ and $-1$. For example, if $n=2$, the first summation would be over $\{\{1,1\},\{1,-1\},\{-1,1\},\{-1,-1\}\}$. If $a=\{1,-1\}$, then $a_1=1$ and $a_2=-1$.

$||x|| = $ norm of $x$.

I think it can be done using the NMaximize function (or is there a better way?). We can take $v_i$ in polar coordinates and then the number of parameters required to specify all vectors would be $2n$. Since the vectors are also rotationally symmetric, we could also fix one vector as $v_1=(1,0,0)$, thus reducing the number of parameters to $2(n-1)$.

How do you do this?

Comment: Is this the 2-norm, or something else? You seem to be taking the norm of a scalar, in any event.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui M    It is the 2-norm. I am taking the norm of a vector. $v_i$ are vectors. It's taking the norm of the sum of vectors, where the coefficients are given by $a_i$.

Comment: Ah, so for e.g. $n=3$, your unknowns are $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ (with nine scalar unknowns all in all)?

Comment: yes, that's right...actually my problem is more detailed with additional constraints... but I want to know if this simple case would work in mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried implementing this with `NMaximize` yet ? This is how it might look naïvely:

```
Remove["Global`*"]

n = 3;
a = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n];
vars = Array[v, n*n];

objective[vars_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] :=
 With[{vecs = Partition[vars, n]},
  Sum[Norm[Total[vecs*ai]], {ai, a}, Method -> "Procedural"]
  ]

(* Max[Abs[vars]] < 1 is a constraint I added for demonstration sake *)
{err, sol} = NMaximize[{objective[vars], Max[Abs[vars]] < 1}, vars]
vectors = Partition[Values[sol], n];
```